Unable to Register a Sole Propietor Messaging Campaign
My campaign was rejected on
ERROR: 30896

"The campaign submission has been reviewed and it was rejected because of provided Opt-in information."
The opt-in info I provided is: "Users can opt in by texting DANCE or START to +1 (336) 699-6960. Message and data rates may apply."
I am hoping to create a campaign where the opt in is only conducted via SMS (i.e. users don't have to visit a website). Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

I believe you need to include the business name in the OPT-IN message provided to the user.
The script I use is:
Opt_in Example 1:
Hello {{contact_first_name}}, it's {{friendly_business_name}}. Thank you for opting in to receive our messages! Feel free to contact us anytime for assistance or account inquiries. Standard messaging and data rates may apply. To stop receiving messages, simply reply with STOP.
Opt_in Example 2:
Hey {{contact_first_name}}! This is {{account_representatives_name}} from {{friendly_business_name}}. Thank you for inquiring about the item we have for sale. Would you like to schedule a time to meet, so that you can look it over in person? Reply STOP to unsubscribe.

This is my full opt in message (which is still getting denied)
CLUBSTACK ALERT SYSTEMS ™ -- You are now opted in to our ALERT SYSTEM We will notify you of upcoming dance events. -- You may opt out at any time by replying STOP. Msg & data rates may apply. Terms & privacy.
